# How do you ignore a directory using .dockerignore?

Tags: docker

I'd like to ignore a directory using `.dockerignore` but it seems like its not doing anything. Is my syntax wrong?

```
timothy@nixos ~/p/d/standalone (bad-auth) [17]> cat .dockerignore
db/
timothy@nixos ~/p/d/standalone (bad-auth)> docker-compose build
[+] Building 2.2s (5/17)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                              0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.10-slim-bullseye      1.4s
 => [ 1/13] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.10-slim-bullseye@sha256:829bfd6812e2  0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load build context                                           0.7s
 => => transferring context: 61.51MB                                              0.7s
------
 > [internal] load build context:
------
failed to solve: error from sender: open /home/timothy/pu/django-helpdesk/standalone/db: permission denied
```

Here I have a directory `./db` which is a docker volume in the docker-compose file I'm using. Naturally, this directory is owned by root and cannot be read. "No problem" I think, I'll just ignore it. But adding it to the `.dockerignore` file does nothing. Is my syntax wrong? I tried both `db` and `db/`

Comment: Syntax is correct, `db/` ignores the `db`-directory that is located in the same directory as the `.dockerignore`-file. Please [edit] the post and provide a [MRE].